# Write Breezejs data source provider with Nodejs for MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, breeze

I would like to use Breeze with NodeJS and MySQL. Unfortunately, so far I could find no examples of this. I have seen that there is an example of NodeJS + MongoDB. Now I try to analyze the MongoDB provider (mongoSaveHandler.js - [npm install breeze-mongodb]?) to write my own provider for MySQL. Unfortunately I could not find any documentation on how such a provider must be established.

The provider should be able to deal with complex data and navigation properties (one-to-many, etc.) and also save/delete/update them properly in the MySQL database.

The following is an example of how the database structure might look like:

[Database Image](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3WCKs18q8v4/UjsG-E3guMI/AAAAAAAAAAs/NjdFIOWAXLw/w575-h500-no/Database.png)

My questions are now:

- Is there already an example with Breeze (+NodeJS) and MySQL that I could use?
- Is there a documentation/sample how to write a own data source provider?
- If I'm on my own, what should I look for when I create my provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of Web API+EF+SQL samples, the Node+MongoDB sample you've already seen, a Ruby+SQL sample, and even a NoDB (and 3rd party data) sample ... but no Node+SQL sample yet.

These docs aren't spot on for your use case, but they will likely point you in the right direction:

**ToDo Server**

The docs are for [Web API+EF+SQL](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-server), but good detail on how everything is wired together.

**MongoDB**

The [MongoDB docs](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb) as well as the [Zza! sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza) are pretty good about showing how they configured the Node server (to talk with MongoDB, sure, but you can see the process all the same).